# How to know if Bzr is currently locked?

Tags: version-control, bazaar

i need a way to check if Bazaar is currently locked (performing locking operations), via shell command.

Any workaround is good as long as is fast to accomplish (1, 2 seconds, not more).

If possible, I would steer clear filesystem-path based solutions. If possible.

Any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out you can check if a directory is locked by simply using:

```
bzr info
```